# Overwrite WordPress Permalink Structure with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add some rewrite rules to my htaccess file, but I can't seem to get around the permalink structure. Here's what I'm trying:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# BEGIN MyRules

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^properties/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ?property=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^properties/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ?property=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^agents/(.*)$ ?agent=$1
RewriteRule ^agents/(.*)/$ ?agent=$1
</IfModule>

# END MyRules

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

WordPress keeps rendering "properties" and "agents" as categories, but since those categories don't exist, I get a 404 error. These are actually pages, and I'd like to get the parameters passed to those pages to rewrite the url.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that WordPress is already passing other parameters to the index such as "name," and "category," since the structure I'm trying to rewrite is similar to the custom permalink structure I'm using.

I was able to remove these parameters like this:

```
RewriteRule ^properties/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$  /index.php?property=$1&page=$2&cateogry=&name= [L]
```

Michel's advice above isn't wrong, but this specifically fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your rules and added comments

You should not repeat the whole block. Apache might ( didn't verify ) just forget the first "`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block when you add another one

I didn't verify your regular expressions but they're looking fine syntax wise

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # enable the rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On
    # "/" is the base path to work on
    RewriteBase /

    # dont rewrite calls on index.php
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # rewrite the url to index.php and pass query values
    # [L] indicates, that apache does not need to care 
    # about the following rewrites when this matches
    RewriteRule ^properties/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$  /index.php?property=$1&page=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^agents/(.*)/?$ /index.php?agent=$1

    # If the request does not point to a existing file ( image.jpg )
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # If the request does not point to a existing directory ( /, default index.php )
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # in this cases you would usually say "404 not found" but no, 
    # please direct all those to the index.php which will care of the rest
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down for me. It makes sense, but WordPress still insists on treating "properties" and "agents" as if they were categories. For example, if I try: mysite.com/agents/user.name/, WordPress forwards me to my 404 template because agents isn't a valid category and user.name isn't a valid post.

Comment: So which page would you like to display under agents/* and properties/* do those pages exist in wordpress / how would you open this pages without rewrite?

Comment: I would like the agents and properties pages to grab the parameters passed to them, but rewrite the url in a more friendly format. For example, if someone went to the /agents page, they would get an archive of all agents, but if they went to /agents/user.name (which is really /agents/?agent=user.name), they would get results only for that specific user.